# DataBound combobox selected index - 1 issue

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am having issue with resetting my databound combobox to `cmb.SelectedIndex = -1`

Basically as per the title, the combo box is bound to a datasource and I have a reset button click event which sets the combox box selected index to -1. Main aim is to set the resultant to `null`.

However when I click the reset button it goes to the first item and then I have to click the button again which then sets the index to -1. So it seems like it goes to selectedIndex 1 and then -1? I am confused?

Here is the code

```
public SetupBindings()
{
    cmb.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ComboBox.SelectedValue), DataSource,
            nameof(DataSource.ID), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}

public void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmb.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing your all relavent code. Where does `setupbindings()` get called? Is there anything else you do other than these two methods?

Comment: Also, `SelectedIndex = 1` means second item. Indices start at 0.

Comment: @Sach setupbindings gets called when I load the `UserControl`

Comment: I have a feeling databound combobox resets only to 0 instead of -1?

Comment: If selected index -1 doesn't working then you should try to clear combobox and bind it again.

Comment: `cbo.DataBindings[0].BindingManagerBase.SuspendBinding();`

Comment: Using a BindingSource, you could stop the events notification with `BindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;`. See also: [BindingSource.ResetBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings).

Comment: ok seems like I found the solution. I tried clearing the list, reassigning the datasource to combobox but it still didn't work. So in the end I set the datasource property in this case `ID` to null which reset the combobox. :)